# Reading a line of binary file MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file, binary, fread

I am new in using `MATLAB` and I want to do a simple thing: I want to read a binary file that contains rows like this

```
32156432

345243867

454154351

35477

5641871

....
```

I know that the `fread()` in MATLAB reads the file byte by byte, but I want to read the value that there is on each line. All values are `uint32_t` and the file is generated with a script in `C++` with just a `printf`, the values are printed in a file like `my_file.bin` launching the executable in this way `./executable param1 >> my_file.bin`

Comment: That's not a binary file, it's a text file containing ASCII-coded numbers. Binary files don't have rows anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function [`fscanf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html)

Sample Code:

```
fileID = fopen('my_file.bin','w');
x = 32156432;
y = 345243867;
w = 454154351;
fprintf(fileID, '%d\n',x);
fprintf(fileID, '%d\n',y);
fprintf(fileID, '%d\n',w);
fclose(fileID);

fileID = fopen('my_file.bin','r');
formatSpec = '%d';
A = fscanf(fileID, formatSpec);
```